# Password expression is not working as expected

Tags: java, regex, passwords

> I have a password expression like below.

It has to allow either one small letter, one capital letter, one numeric or one small letter, one capital letter , one special character or one small letter, one capital letter, one numeric, one special character. I joined all the three conditions using | or. It should be min of 8 and max 20 characters. It should allow only specific special characters $@#!%. But here it is allowing all the special characters though I mentioned specific set. Thats the main issue. I spent lot time in changing patterns but still the same allowing all special characters. –

> I don't understand why its allowing ^ (Marr1234^)?

(((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$@#!%]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$@#!%]))|((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]))).{8,20}

> Any ideas

Comment: I don't understand what's your actual question is.

Comment: My password is allowing ^ , I dont have ^ in my regualr expression.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve? Any hint?

Comment: it would be great so see the code with which you actually try to check for the match...

Comment: ok, my passowrd should allow only specific special characters $@#!% but I dont understand why it is allowing ^. My regualar expression is as fallows. (((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$@#!%]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$@#!%]))|((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]))).{8,20}

Comment: please, update your question - people are not required to figure out what your are asking from the comments. The regexp you use is visible. But what's your java code so that we can give it a try? and what's the exact string you are surprised that it gets a match? `Marr1234^`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks rdmuller for the help. I was able to fix it. 
I need to add the range [A-Za-z0-9] and avoid "." like .{8,20}.

Here is the expression I used

^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[A-Za-z0-9]{8,20}$

Comment: Great! So I wish you all the best for your next interactions on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about `.{8,20}` matching your input? This term matches every character (`.`==every character) 8 up to 20 times... So this would also match the `^`-character

Comment: waht could be possibel solution for my case

Comment: How should I avoid the .{8,20} where I need to mention the password min and max range. Is there any possible solution for this                                                                                                         (((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$@#!%]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[$@#!%]))|((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]))).{8,20}

Comment: I am a little bit puzzled by your regexp. Can you describe in word what you would like to match?

Comment: It has to allow either one small letter, one capital letter, one numeric or one small letter, one capital letter , one special character or one small letter, one capital letter, one numeric, one special character. I joined all the three conditions using | or. It should be min of 8 and max 20 characters. It should allow only specific special characters $@#!%. But here it is allowing all the special characters though I mentioned specific set. Thats the main issue. I spent lot time in changing patterns but still the same allowing all special characters.

Comment: btw: it is common netiquette to upvote answers which helped ;-)